# How do you print a multipage tiff file using CUPS (lp command)?

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, tiff, multipage

On Linux system (Ubuntu) I have a multipage TIFF file (file.tiff).

When I send it to a printer using "lp file.tiff" command, only the first page prints.

How do I print all the pages?

I have the following known options:

1. Split the file to single-page TIFFs
2. Convert TIFF to PDF

I'd like to keep the multi-page TIFF and avoid creating other formats. Is there a way to make CUPS print all the pages from the multipage TIFF file?

(Please do not offer "convert the file" as an answer as I know those, I'm looking for a CUPS method, lpprintmultipagetiff --please?).

Answer (score 0):

Use tiff2ps. The link is below. You could also setup a dirty loop to print each page manually with cups.

```
for((i=1;i<=884;i++)); do <your lpr print command>; done
```

Note: 884 is the last page number... I'm just guessing. Use $i in your lpr print command when printing the desired page.

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_tiff2ps.htm

Comment: tiff2ps is conversion to another format, and I was very specific asking to not offer conversions. The rest of the solution is incomplete and it is not clear how it should work. Pick up a page # from converted PS file? Or from TIFF file? As far as I can get out of lp commands, they cannot extract page number from TIFF.

Comment: Does something like the following work?    "lp -o page-ranges=1 filename" or
    "lp -o page-ranges=1-4 filename" or
    "lp -o page-ranges=1-4,7,9-12 filename" or
    "lpr -o page-ranges=1-4,7,9-12 filename".